# Reset value in Simulink mask

Tags: simulink, mask

How can I reset a value of a Simulink mask parameter each time the 'MaskVisibilities' is set to 'off'? I tried to set the value in a callback which set the visibility at on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with:

```
param = get_param(gcb, 'MaskValues');
param{length(param)} = '20';
set_param(gcb, 'MaskValues', param);
```

Now, my last parameter is set to 20 each time the callback is executed (to set the 'Visibilities' to 'off').